# Merge two dataframes based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to compare name column in two dataframes df1 and df2 , output the matching rows from dataframe df1 and store the result in new dataframe df3. How do i do this in Pandas ?

df1

```
place name qty unit
NY    Tom   2  10
TK    Ron   3  15
Lon   Don   5  90
Hk    Sam   4  49
```

df2

```
place name price 
PH    Tom   7    
TK    Ron   5
```

Result:

df3

```
place name qty unit
NY    Tom   2  10
TK    Ron   3  15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Using `df.isin`:

```
In [1362]: df1[df1.name.isin(df2.name)]
Out[1362]: 
  place name  qty  unit
0    NY  Tom    2    10
1    TK  Ron    3    15
```

---

**Option 2**

Performing an inner-join with `df.merge`:

```
In [1365]: df1.merge(df2.name.to_frame())
Out[1365]: 
  place name  qty  unit
0    NY  Tom    2    10
1    TK  Ron    3    15
```

---

**Option 3**

Using `df.eq`:

```
In [1374]: df1[df1.name.eq(df2.name)]
Out[1374]: 
  place name  qty  unit
0    NY  Tom    2    10
1    TK  Ron    3    15
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something called an inner join.

```
df1.merge(df2,on = 'name')

place_x name    qty unit place_y price
NY      Tom      2  10     PH      7
TK      Ron      3  15     TK      5
```

The `_x`and `_y` happens when you have a column in both data frames being merged.

Comment: I've already covered this in my answer, and besides, this has more columns than what OP wants.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm leaving it up in case it is helpful to another user.  If OP finds your answer most helpful, he can accept it.