# Merge two dataframes based on a column with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I know how to merge two dataframes based on a specific column when there aren't duplicates[1].

```
new = new[new.name.isin(old.exchange_time)]
old = old[old.name.isin(new.exchange_time)]
```

How can I do it when there are more duplicate entries in one but not the other? For example:

new

```
place name qty unit
NY    Tom   3  10
NY    Tom   4  10
TK    Ron   3  15
Lon   Don   5  90
Hk    Sam   4  49
```

old

```
place name qty unit
NY    Tom   2  10
NY    Tom   2  10
NY    Tom   2  10 <-- this should be discarded
TK    Ron   3  15
Hk    Sam   4  49
```

I want a solution that keeps the first few entries and discards the latter duplicate entries if there ceases to be overlap. In the above example, the third `Tom` row should be deleted since there are only two `Tom` rows in `new`.

Desired output of new

```
place name qty unit
NY    Tom   3  10
NY    Tom   4  10
TK    Ron   3  15
Hk    Sam   4  49
```

Desired output of old

```
place name qty unit
NY    Tom   2  10
NY    Tom   2  10
TK    Ron   3  15
Hk    Sam   4  49
```

[1] [Merge two dataframes based on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809201/merge-two-dataframes-based-on-a-column)

Comment: what about getting unique rows from `old` and than join to `new`?

Comment: I would clean up the dataframe with duplicates first. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-drop_duplicates/

Comment: @Pierluigi I want to keep the first two duplicates, so can't take uniques

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: @JuanC Added that to the question.

Comment: @JacksonCounty I think that `left join` if what you are looking for

Comment: Are those columns actual total duplicates? Don't you have more columns with some variation?

Comment: @JuanC It's just an example.

Comment: I know, but you're example is not totally reproducible, because we don't know if there's some order to said columns. Our answer might give you wrong results in the future if your example is incomplete. Now the only criterium is "repeat as many times as the first dataframe" which is quite arbitrary and might lead to future error